# Num list, qual é a diferença entre append e extend?

Tags: python, lista

Num `list` em Python, existem os métodos `append` e `extend`.

Qual é a diferença entre eles e quando devo usar cada um?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### [`extend()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html?#array.array.extend)

Recebe um "*iterable*" como parâmetro e estende a lista adicionando os elementos dele

```
lista = [1, 2, 3]
lista.extend([4, 5])
print(lista) 
# Saída: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

#### [`append()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html?#array.array.append)

adiciona um elemento no final da lista

```
lista = [1, 2, 3]
lista.append([4, 5])
print(lista) 
# Saída: [1, 2, 3, [4, 5]]
```

Comment: Sei que não é legal comparar outras linguagens com Python, até trazer costumes de outras para o Python. Mas seria equivalente ao `List<T>.AddRange()` do .NET?

Comment: @vnbrs O `extend` sim

Answer (score 12):

No `append()` você adiciona elementos ao fim da lista, no `extend()` é esperado uma *iterable* como argumento, e esse argumento é adicionado ao fim da lista elemento por elemento.

Se você tem uma lista e quer incluir elementos de outra lista nela, você deve usar o `extend()`; caso contrário, ele adicionará uma lista ao final da sua lista.

Exemplo:

```
lista1 = [1, 2, 3]
lista1.append([4, 5])
print lista1
# resultado: [1, 2, 3, [4, 5]]

lista2 = [1, 2, 3]
lista2.extend([4, 5])
print lista2
# resultado: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

lista3 = [1, 2, 3]
lista3.append(4)
print lista3
# resultado: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/ee6lCo).

Answer (score 10):

- `append` irá adicionar qualquer `list` como um item

  ```
  foo = [1, 2, 3]
  foo.append([4, 5])
  print foo
  ```

  Retorna: `[1, 2, 3, [4, 5]]`
- `extend` iterá os elementos, seria quase como um "merge"

  ```
  foo = [1, 2, 3]
  foo.extend([4, 5])
  print foo
  ```

  Retorna: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Do SOen: https://stackoverflow.com/a/252711/1518921

Exemplo no ideone: http://ideone.com/2EgMan

Comment: Tomei a liberdade de trocar `array` por `list`, meu jovem :p

Comment: @WallaceMaxters força do habito minha :) Obrigado