# Adicionar um novo valor à uma lista

Tags: python

Existe alguma forma de adicionar um novo valor à uma lista em Python a partir de uma entrada de usuário?

Exemplo:

```
Entrada = int(input("Digite um número"))    
lista = [] #A partir da entrada acima eu gostaria de expandir esta lista
```

Comment: Relacionada: [Num list, qual é a diferença entre append e extend?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/170745/18246)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim. Usando [`append`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html?#array.array.append)

```
lista.append(Entrada)
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou.