# Adicionar mais de um elemento ao Append é possível?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Consigo adicionar mais de um elemento na função `append`?

Por exemplo:

```
convite.append("Carlos", "Junior") 
convite["Alberto", "Eduardo"]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Com o método `append` não é possível. Se olhar a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) verá que ele aceita apenas um parâmetro:

> `list.append(x)`
>
> *Add an item to the end of the list. Equivalent to `a[len(a):] = [x]`.*

Mas você pode adicionar mais elementos através do operador de soma, `+`:

```
nomes = ['Anderson']
nomes += ['Carlos', 'Woss']

print(nomes) # ['Anderson', 'Carlos', 'Woss']
```

Ou até fazer como o próprio `append` faz:

```
nomes = ['Anderson']
nomes[len(nomes):] = ['Carlos', 'Woss']

print(nomes) # ['Anderson', 'Carlos', 'Woss']
```

Ainda existe, também, o método `extends`, comentado nesta pergunta:

- [Num list, qual é a diferença entre append e extend?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/170741/5878)

Comment: +1 por demonstrar como Python pode simplificar

Answer (score 1):

Sua pergunta indica que não estudou bem a documentação quanto ao método append ou o uso da linguagem como um todo, especificamente acerca de loops.
De qualquer maneira, você pode usar um *for loop* pra isso:

```
convite = list()
for i in ["Alberto", "Eduardo"]:
    convite.append(i)

print(convite)
>>> ["Alberto", "Eduardo"]
```