# Erro "IndexError: list assignment index out of range" ao setar "l[0] ="

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

Eu to tendo um problema na minha classe
na função **__init__()**

```
class Lutador():
    __nome = "null"
    __nacionalidade = 'null'
    __idade = 0
    __altura = 0.0
    __peso = 0.0
    __categoria = 'null'
    __vitorias = 0
    __derrostas = 0
    __empates = 0

    #Métodos Especias

    def __init__(self,no,na,ida,al,pe,vi,de,em):
        self.__nome = no
        self.__nacionalidade = na
        self.__idade = ida
        self.__altura = al
        self.setPeso(pe)
        self.__vitorias = vi
        self.__derrotas = de
        self.__empates = em


    def getNome(self):
        return self.__nome

    def setNome(self,nome):
        self.__nome = nome

    def getNacionalidade(self):
        return self.__nacionalidade

    def setNacionalidade(self,nacionalidade):
        self.__nacionalidade = nacionalidade

    def getIdade(self):
        return self.__idade

    def setIdade(self,idade):
        self.__idade = idade

    def getAltura(self):
        return self.__altura

    def setAltura(self,altura):
        self.__altura = altura

    def getPeso(self):
        return self.__peso

    def setPeso(self,peso):
        self.__peso = peso
        self.setCategoria()

    def getCategoria(self):
        return self.__categoria

    def setCategoria(self):
        if (self.__peso<52.2):
            self.__categoria = "Inválido"
        elif (self.__peso<=70.3):
            self.__categoria = "Leve"
        elif (self.__peso<=83.9):
            self.__categoria = "Médio"
        elif (self.__peso<=120.2):
            self.__categoria = "Pesado"
        else:
            self.__categoria = "Inválido"

    def getVitorias(self):
        return self.__vitorias

    def setVitorias(self,vitorias):
        self.__vitorias = vitorias

    def getDerrostas(self):
        return self.__derrostas

    def setDerrostas(self,derrostas):
        self.__derrostas = derrostas

    def getEmpates(self):
        return self.__empates

    def setEmpates(self,empates):
        self.__empates = empates

    #Métodos

    def apresentar():
        print("-----------------------------------------")
        print(f"CHEGOU A HORA! Apresentamos o lutador {self.getNome()}")
        print(f"Diretamente de {self.getNacionalidade()}")
        print(f"Com {self.getIdade()} anos {self.getAltura()}m")
        print(f"Pesando {self.getPeso()} kg")
        print(f"{self.getVitorias()} vitorias")
        print(f"{self.getDerrotas()} derrotas")
        print(f"{self.getEmpates()} empates")

    def status():
        print(f"{self.getNome()} é um peso {self.getCategoria()}")
        print(f"Ganhou {self.getVitorias()} vezes")
        print(f"Perdeu {self.getDerrotas()} vezes")
        print(f"Empatou {self.getEmpates()} vezes")

    def ganharLuta():
        self.setVitorias(self.getVitorias() + 1)

    def perderLuta():
        self.setDerrotas(self.getDerrotas() + 1)

    def empatarLuta():
        self.setEmpates(self.getEmpates() + 1)

# Programa principal

l = []
l[0] = Lutador("Pretty Boy", "França", 31, 1.75, 68.9, 11, 2, 1)
```

Quando eu executo dá um erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fbcode/PooPython/07/UltraEmojiCombat.py", line 5, in <module>
    l[0] = Lutador("Pretty Boy", "França", 31, 1.75, 68.9, 11, 2, 1)
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

O que eu devo fazer?

Obrigado pela atenção

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está fazendo uma atribuição em uma posição que não existe na lista. Como você iniciou a lista como vazia, não existirá a posição 0 e, portanto, não conseguirá fazer a atribuição.

Se a ideia é adicionar um elemento na lista, utilize o método `append`:

```
l.append(Lutador("Pretty Boy", "França", 31, 1.75, 68.9, 11, 2, 1))
```

Se quiser adicionar mais de um elemento por vez, pode utilizar o operador `+`, como comentado nesta resposta:

- [Adicionar mais de um elemento ao Append é possível?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/365526/5878)

Outros pontos que podem ser considerados no seu código:

- Em Python não há o costume de se definir *getters* e *setters* como fez, bastante comum em outras linguagens. No seu caso, como quase não há nenhuma regra de negócio nos seus métodos, você pode definir os seus campos como "públicos";
- Para os campos que demandam certas regras de negócio, você poderá definir uma [propriedade](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property);