# Valor Iterável e único

Tags: python, append, números

Isso não é um problema, é uma dúvida, então espero que possam me ajudar.

Eu sou iniciante em python, e estou aprendendo sobre listas, e o professor fala sobre elementos únicos e iteráveis.

Eu queria saber a diferença entre eles. Eu fiz um teste, mas foi no cmd.

```
lista1 = list(range(11))

lista1.append(14)

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 14]

lista1.append([14])

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 14, [14]]


lista1.extend(55)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

lista1.extend([55])

[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 14, [15], 13]
```

Mais abaixo, tem a imagem.

[image: Teste no cmd]

Comment: No exemplo é 55 ou 13?

Answer (score 0):

Como também detalhado nesta outra [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/170741/num-list-qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-append-e-extend), o método extend() espera como parâmetro um objeto iterável (por exemplo outra lista) e não um primitivo (como um int).

Note que quando você utiliza o método append você tem a opção de adicionar objetos iteráveis ou não à sua lista. Por exemplo:
`lista1.append([15])`
está adicionando uma lista com um único elemento (o 15) ao final da lista1 e não o elemento 15.

Comment: Valeu cara, me ajudou muito, tava procurando a meia hora o significado disso. E agora sei a diferença do 'extend()' e do 'append()'. Valeu.

Comment: @PTheDark Poderia aprovar essa resposta ou alguma outra?

Answer (score 0):

"Eu queria saber a diferença entre eles."

**Elemento único**: elementos que do tipo value, que só podem ter um valor, (int, float, char, byte, double, decimal,etc...), são os tipos primitivos.

**Elemento iterável**: geralmente é uma estrutura de dado, que pode conter muitos valores, e no caso do python pode contar valores de diferentes tipos de dados (tipos únicos). Iteráveis geralmente são do tipo reference (faz referencia à um endereço na memoria), exemplos: listas/arrays, tuplas e acho que também strings, mas as strings (que são uma sequência de char) você não pode mudar o valor das posições, apenas percorrer. A grosso modo, elemento iterável é tudo aquilo que vc pode percorrer com notação de index.

Answer (score -1):

Um iterável é um tipo que pode ser percorrido. Uma lista possui vários elementos e você pode percorrer eles lendo seus valores. (Debaixo dos panos, esses tipos possuem o método **iter** implementado).

No caso do inteiro, você possui apenas um valor, não tem como você percorrer ele listando os valores.