# Adicionar conteúdo ao dicionário dentro de um laço for em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for, dicionário

Estou fazendo uns projetos individuais para aprender melhor a programar em python e estou tendo uma certa dúvida usando dicionários.

```
import pandas as pd

sumario = {'Nome do Aluno': [],
            'Nota do Aluno': [],
           'Situação': []}

alunos = int(input('Quantos alunos há na sala ? '))

for c in range(1, alunos+1):
  nomes = input(f'Qual o nome do {c}° aluno ? ').strip().title()
  notas = int(input(f'Qual a nota de {nomes} ? '))
  if notas > 5:
    situacao = 'Aprovado'
  else:
    situacao = 'Reprovado'


sumario_df = pd.DataFrame(sumario)
display(sumario_df)
```

Este é o meu código. A estrutura permanece funcional e o modelo do dicionário eu quero deste jeito, mas eu gostaria de criar um dataframe com o dicionário. Eu tentei utilizar

```
sumario = {'Nome do Aluno': [nomes],
           'Nota do Aluno': [notas],
           'Situação': [situacao]
           }
```

Mas aparentemente, fazendo isso ele atribui o último valor, e não adiciona. Tentei também de outro jeito

```
sumario['Nome do Aluno'] = nomes
sumario['Nota do Aluno'] = notas
sumario['Situação'] = situacao
```

Mas o resultado foi o mesmo, acredito que para conseguir adicionar seja utilizando keys e values mas não sei como se usa. Se puder me ajudar eu agradeço muito.

Comment: Veja se o exemplo o ajuda https://ideone.com/3FHHDj . Também veja as [operações comuns a sequencias mutaveis](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types)

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Num list, qual é a diferença entre append e extend?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/170741/num-list-qual-%c3%a9-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-append-e-extend)

Answer (score -1):

Quando for trabalha com dicionrios ou listas sempre pense que os elementos contidos neles tem que serem trabalhados unitariamente, ou seja, você precisa incluir um a um na sua lista/dicionário.

Eu modifique seu exemplo com a forma que isso tem que ser feito, veja abaixo.

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display

alunos = []

total_alunas_sala = int(input('Quantos alunos há na sala ? '))

for c in range(1, total_alunas_sala+1):
  nome = input(f'Qual o nome do {c}° aluno ? ').strip().title()
  nota = int(input(f'Qual a nota de {nome} ? '))
  if nota > 5:
    situacao = 'Aprovado'
  else:
    situacao = 'Reprovado'
  
  aluno = {
    'Nome do Aluno':nome,
    'Nota do Aluno': nota,
    'Situação': situacao
  }
  
  alunos.append(aluno)

sumario_df = pd.DataFrame(alunos)
display(sumario_df)
```

Aqui é criado um dicionario de um aluno:

```
aluno = {
        'Nome do Aluno':nome,
        'Nota do Aluno': nota,
        'Situação': situacao
      }
```

depois esse aluno é incluido em uma lista.

```
 alunos.append(aluno)
```

Assim você tem sua lista com todos os alunos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O exemplo está no [github](https://github.com/MarconcilioSouza/stackoverflow_respostas/blob/main/adicionar-conteudo-ao-dicionario-dentro-de-um-for-em-python.py) para referencias.